# Why am I logged out every morning?

Tags: support, bug, login

Every morning when I first open Stack Overflow ( or other SE sites ) I am logged out. I'm sure that I used to stay logged in for ages, but now it only seems to last for the day, possibly even just the browser session.

I tried following the advice of a question here and clearing all StackOverflow related cookies, which worked for a day or two but then I was back to being logged out each morning.

Consequently I have found problems with the log-in page. As a LiveJournal user ( I know, probably the last one ) when I put my LJ account into the "log-in" box and click "log in" it doesn't autofill the full OpenID provider box below, so then it gets very confused because there is nowhere for it to go. This behaviour appears to work the first time I visit that page but after that it fails consistently. My first guess would be that if the page is opened with the "More OpenID Options" section already visible ( as happens on return visits to the page, but not on the first visit ) the event handler may not get properly attached. If I manually type the full provider url in the box, it works as expected.

There is also no kind of "remember me" option on the log-in page. Perhaps the absence thereof is related to my relentless log-out troubles.

Using Chrome 44.0.2403.125.

( I originally asked this question on meta.stackoverflow but moving it here as that didn't seem to garner any suggestions and it was pointed out this is occurring across the SE network. )

Comment: They're subtly trying to say *go away.* ;) On a more serious note, I'm pretty sure I can't repro, using the same version of Chrome as yours.

Comment: It seems likely to me that something weird is happening with my authentication cookies or that there is a persistent identifier that I should have which is somehow absent.

Comment: Any extensions that block third-party cookies?

Comment: Nope, Chrome is close to vanilla aside from  a couple of REST client extensions.

Comment: Quick solution would be to add another OpenID, which is more common. As far as I see it, it's 99% a problem with LiveJournal OpenID mechanism.

Comment: I would guess that all the secondary OpenID providers on that page will have the same problem, which really narrows down my options. If those providers don't work by design, surely SE should be removing that part of the form? If they don't work by mistake then hopefully that can be easily fixed.

Comment: To be clear, the OpenID problem is not on the LiveJournal side, it is occurring on the StackExchange Login page when I click on "more OpenID providers" then select "LiveJournal" from the short list of icons there and click the "Log In" button. The first time I visit that page this creates the LJ OpenID address on the bottom of the form, after that it puts nothing there and consequently the form doesn't submit. It's workaroundable, but it's a bug.